# TypeError: integer argument expected, got float with apply()

Tags: python, datetime, typeerror

I try,

```
closure2['NEXT_PERF_DT'] = closure2['perf_dt'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime((x.year)+(x.month/12), (x.month%12)+1,1))
```

But I get,

```
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Closure2 has only 2 columns:

```
perf_dt         10002 non-null datetime64[ns]
unknown_exit    10002 non-null int64
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the full error message and a sample of the dataset.

Comment: I solved this issue by using the  following code:   closure2['NEXT_PERF_DT'] = closure2['perf_dt'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(int((x.year)+(x.month/12)), int((x.month%12)+1),1))